# MYSQL subsorting when summed up total values are equal

Tags: mysql, sql

UPDATE: Reformatted the whole question

I have a database with individual Formula 1 race results. Each driver gets points for the according to the place they finish in. Now I want to build a table with all combined points from all races for every driver. So basically a "driver standings" table.

I can get the summed up points easily of course but the problem I face comes when multiple drivers have the exact same total points. In these cases I need to check which one of the drivers had the best (or more of them) single race result as he should be above on the end table.

Oh, and on the placement column the "0" means did not finish so that's the worst outcome.

---

Simple example:

```
Event  | Driver    | Placement | Points
--------------------------------------
Race 1 | Driver A  | 1         | 3
Race 1 | Driver B  | 2         | 2
Race 1 | Driver C  | 3         | 1
Race 2 | Driver A  | 3         | 3
Race 2 | Driver B  | 2         | 2
Race 2 | Driver C  | 1         | 1
Race 3 | Driver A  | 0         | 0
Race 3 | Driver B  | 0         | 0
Race 3 | Driver C  | 2         | 2
```

And requested finished table

```
Driver    | Points
------------------
Driver C  | 4
Driver A  | 4
Driver B  | 4
```

Order is because Driver C has one first place finish and a second place finish. Driver A has one first place finish and a third place finish where as Driver B only has second place finishes. (Assuming my head works, it's very late.)

Hard example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16f9c5

Desired result

```
| Driver        | Points |
|------------------------|
| N. Hulkenberg | 43     |
| F. Massa      | 43     |
| P. Wehrlein   |  5     |
| D. Kvyat      |  5     |
| M. Ericsson   |  0     |
| P. Gasly      |  0     |
| A. Giovinazzi |  0     |
| B. Hartley    |  0     |
```

From the fiddle data I dropped everything except the problem cases. Everyone has same points with at least one other, and the tie breakers vary from simple best finish in a race to number of best finishes (four 6th place wins is better than 2 6th place wins like is the case with Hulkenberg and Massa).

The result table is because:

```
1. N. Hulkenberg - has four 6th place finishes
2. F. Massa      - has two 6th place finishes
3. P. Wehrlein   - has 8th place finish
4. D. Kvyat      - has 9th place finish
5. M. Ericsson   - has 11th place finish
6. P. Gasly      - has 12th and 13th place finishes
7. A. Giovinazzi - has only one 12th place finish and nothing else
8. B. Hartley    - has 13th place finish
```

so the real problematic tie breakers are [Hulkenberg vs Massa] and [Gasly vs Giovinazzi]

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sometimes that's the best way. That's what I'd do if soccer teams were tied on goal difference. It is a lot of typing though.

Comment: Sample data and desired results *in the question* really help elucidate the issues.

Comment: So place of highest finish is the first tie break? What's next tie break?

Comment: `CASE WHEN MAX(placement) = 0 then 999 else MAX(placement) end as highest_finish`

Comment: If they are awarded points based on finish, why would revisiting finish break a tie?

Comment: I do not understand your question DaveCoast

Comment: What is the tie breaking rule. If 10th place is 1 point and 1st place is 10 points, does the racer with 1 1st place and 10 point get ranked higher than the racer with 10 10th place finishes. In your fiddle both Massa and Hulkenberg have at tie at best race of 6th. Is it just the number of count of best results - does two 6th place beat 1 6th place and 4 7th place?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. 2 6th place results is better than 1 6th place result and a million worse results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick without too much fuzz.

```
SELECT     
    driver   
   ,SUM(points) AS points  
   ,CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(IF(placement = 0, 99, LPAD(placement,2,0)) ORDER BY IF(placement = 0, 99, placement) SEPARATOR ','), ',99') AS best 
FROM   
   f1 
GROUP BY   
   driver  
ORDER BY     
   points DESC,    
   best
```

Or, if you wanna hide the placement sorting data column:

```
SELECT 
    driver
   ,SUM(points) AS points
FROM
    f1
GROUP BY
    driver
ORDER BY 
    points DESC
   ,CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(IF(placement = 0, 99, LPAD(placement,2,0)) ORDER BY IF(placement = 0, 99, placement) SEPARATOR ','), ',99')
```

It simply takes advantage of alphanumerical sorting to determine best placement(s) in case of a tie in points.

Comment: All racers do not have the same amount of races all the time, but it still seems to give the correct output on the whole database too indeed. Why do you think this could be a problem? edit: towards the end are all the "third drivers" that dont have the full amount of races https://i.imgur.com/mKDT2g9.png

Comment: A practical example: If A. Giovinazzi was not registered with one unfinished race, he would be ranked above P. Gasly. 
(This could be solved by registering 100 as placement for all races where a driver did not participate).

Comment: But, I did and update to the code which resolves this. It should now work consistently with the data you have.

Comment: Oh, ofc, and ok great! New season starts this weekend so just in the nick of time. Thanks! edit: I'll award the bounty when the site lets me, thanks again.

Comment: No problem, it was a fun head-scratcher for a Friday morning. :-)

Comment: One more question, is there any ups or downs doing the concat on the select or order. I'm laying out the data on a PHP foreach loop so it doesn't matter at all to me if the column is there or not, but I'm wondering if somehow one is faster than the other or something... Both seem to be so fast I can't tell a difference in my PMA,

Comment: This query is lightingly fast no matter what you do, so speed is not an issue here. I usually include such meta info is as it makes debugging easier.

Comment: @jimihenrik Regarding speed: adding an index to the driver column is recommended, as your primary key can not be used by the db-engine is this query (since 'event' comes before driver in the primary key definition). It will not make an impact on a small data set like this, but if this was a huge one, it would have made a noticeable difference in execution time.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know if it changes things but my table structure is this https://i.imgur.com/6Z4Udpo.png

Comment: Note that this would not sort `9` and `11` correctly. Example: `'11,11,...' < '9,9,...'`. So you should use `LPAD(placement, 2, 0)` - Then you would get `'09,09,...' < '11,11,...'`. Here is what I mean: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16f9c5/52 - And the fix: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16f9c5/53

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: well spotted. The query is updated accordingly. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try a self-join.

```
select t1.driver, points, min_placement 
from (select driver, sum(points) points from f1 group by driver) t1 inner join
     (select driver, min(placement) min_placement from f1 group by driver) t2 
  on t1.driver = t2.driver
order by points desc, min_placement asc
```

In your test data, most drivers have a lowest placement of zero, so you won't see the results you're looking for.

Comment: I thought some kind of join would help but am not skillful enough on SQL. And yes I had to cut a lot of data because the max limit on the fiddle. I tried this and it seems to work on the Kvyat Wehrlein case but not on the Massa Hulkenberg case where they both have the best same rank, but the other just has more or of those. Two 1st place positions win over one 1st place position.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you'll need at least a second tie break after highest finish:

```
SELECT
    driver,
    SUM(points) as points,
    CASE WHEN MAX(placement) = 0 THEN 99 ELSE MAX(placement) END AS highest_finish,
    -- or maybe this would work?
    SUM(CASE WHEN placement <> 0
        THEN POWER(20, placement) ELSE 0 END) AS weighted_finish 
FROM f1
GROUP BY driver
ORDER BY points DESC, highest_finish
```

You might also have luck with an expression like this:

```
SELECT f1.driver,
    MAX((100 - f1.placement) * (
        SELECT count(*) FROM f1 f2
        WHERE f2.driver = f1.driver 
          AND f2.placement = f1.placement
          AND f2.placement > 0
        )) AS highest_placement_weight
FROM f1
GROUP BY f1.driver
```

Comment: This doesn't either seem to take account the cases when the highest_finish is the same but the other one has more of them than the other. At least my PMA still returns Massa (two 6th place finishes) above Hulkenberg (four 6th place finishes) when it should be the other way around.

Comment: That why I've been asking what the tie break rules are.

Comment: Yes I understand, and I think I answered on the top post already. But now you know. Thanks!

Comment: Still not sure I've got it straight. Try the powers approach with a base of like 20.

Comment: You have that "-- or maybe this would work?" do you mean those are like two different options, or what's the weighted_finish one now?

Comment: Yes, it would rank a higher finish exponentially higher. You can play with the numbers, I just didn't want an overflow.